# accept only first event emitted by client in socket.io and discard duplicate events

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am a new to node.js and socket.io. I am creating a web application in which there will be hundreds of clients waiting to place bid in product.

We have used jquery timer and when this timer goes to zero, all the clients emit auction closed event to the server.

Now what I need is only one (the first) product close event to be entertained by nodejs server (app.js) and the rest need to be discarded.

```
//client requesting server to close the product     
socket.emit('time_finished', {'id':id,'name':name,'time':time});

//and my server code (receive time finished event from client)
socket.on('time_finished',function(data) {
     //performing product closing operation here
}
```

any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: so you're giving the person with lowest ping a benefit. Why don't you try to measure the time difference between client and server, then entertain the one with the lowest ping?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one product, you can set a boolean to true, after first event arrive.

```
    var alreadySent = false;
    socket.on('time_finished',function(data) {
         if(!alreadySent){
            alreadySent = true;
            //performing product closing operation here
         }
    }
```

but if you have many products, you can save the state in an array or in an external database.

```
    var alreadySentIds = [];
    socket.on('time_finished',function(data) {
         if(alreadySentIds.indexOf(data.productId) == -1){ // not existing
            alreadySentIds.push(data.productId);
            //performing product closing operation here
         }
    }
```